# Excel VBA Macro using Word Template to Compose Outlook Emails opening word template as read only

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

- I have an Excel Sheet with all information to compose a Email
- I'm running Macro to open a Word Template which is a .Docx
  file and fill bookmarks with the data from excel sheet.
- when macro try to open the Word Doc it says ole is in use and the word prompts with three options, read only, merge to local, etc and the message say file is locked by my name.
- I use close and quit to close the template in every loop, but unable to fix it. Am I missing something to close the document properly, so that it opens correctly without file is in use.

```
For iRow = 9 to rng

if ws.cells(iRow,6).value <> Nullstring and ws.cells(iRow, 7).value = "" then

Set objword = createobject("word.application")

bsent = false

objword.visible = true

set objdoc = objword.documents.open(Templatename()) '****here i'm getting error *****

objDoc.bookmarks("applicationname").range.text = ws.cells(iRow,2).value

set olmailitem = olfolder.items.add("IPM.Note")
set olMailitem = objDoc.mailenvelope.item

with olmailitem
 .To = ws.cells(iRow,29).value
.CC = ws.cells(iRow,52).value
.Subject = "some text here"
.attachments.add (filepath)
if bsent = false then .send
.display

end with

<* if open correctly without locking, then it fill in my bookmarks first time>

objdoc.close
objword.quit

set objdoc = nothing
Set objword = nothing 

end if

Next iRow
```

Comment: Where is the loop, can you paste the code with loop ?

Comment: Rather than using `documents.open` try `documents.add` which will open a *copy* of the "template" file, rather than the original file. That should prevent any file lock. Also, it would probably help to set the parameter for the `Close` method to not save changes. IF that doesn't help, then we need enough code to reproduce what you're doing (a [mcve].

Comment: And, seeing the code you posted while I was writing my comment: Take the initialization of `objWord` outside the loop. No need to start and stop Word each time. Start Word before the loop and end it after the loop. Do clean up the document object in each iteration, however.

Comment: Thanks Cindy Meister for the solution, it works fine without locking the file.